# Можно поставить запятую с тире?

Tags: пунктуация

***В 7-9 классах идёт планиметрия, – раздел геометрии, изучающий фигуры на плоскости.*** Можно ли поставить запятую с тире? Знаю, что это обособленное приложение.

Answer (score 2):

1. Я бы использовала в предложении [**наращение**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99): в 7–9-м классах.
2. Запятая перед тире не нужна ([**обособленные приложения, п.8**](https://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/94/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

**В 7–9-м классах идёт планиметрия — раздел геометрии, изучающий фигуры на плоскости.**

Или:
В 7–9-м классах осваивают (или постигают) планиметрию — раздел геометрии, изучающий фигуры на плоскости.